# Why can't I tap Pokémon on the map?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have found ~3 Pokémon out in the wild I have wanted to catch but when I try to tap them on the map but it doesn't do anything. They eventually run away/disappear after a certain period of time.

When I do manage to click on them to start the battle, I can throw the Pokéball just fine. It just sometimes won't load off the map and onto where I catch them I guess.

I do have my location on and have Wifi! I need help to Catch 'Em All!

Comment: Unsure if this is actually a duplicate of that, he could mean before he even gets into that encounter where he throws the ball, you have to tap them in the wild to even get into that.

Comment: I do I am repetedly tapping them but it won't give me the opportunity to catch them.

Comment: Do you see them through the camera or on the map

Comment: Not on the camera, just the map

Comment: Yeah, so not a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think it was a duplicate. I can throw the pokeball just fine. It just won't load off the map and onto where I catch them I guess

Comment: Whenever something in the app stops working, your best bet is to just close and restart it. It's notoriously buggy right now.

Comment: I have edited and reopened this based on the comments.

Answer (score 12):

As of v0.29.0, this is a known bug. Objects on the map will become unresponsive to taps.

The best bet here is to simply close the app (i.e. shut it down, don't just minimize it), and restart the game.

**Additional info**: This bug is known to occur more frequently after making use of the "battery saver" where by the screen goes dark when the device is held upside-down. Waking up the screen again will often cause this bug.

**0.29.2 update** - The bug still exists, but seems rarer. Due to high server load, you will simply not receive data from it, and the game will lag, or stop working.

Comment: +1 for the battery-saver bug mention. This is constantly interfering with gameplay (for myself and a few other people I have spoken to) where items/pokemon/eggs have been lost due to this bug.

Comment: Yeah I turned that thing right off. Any function that causes bugs like that is not worth using.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this bug in v0.29.0 as well. Most often I've had it happen when you try to tap on a Pokemon that is closer to the bottom of the screen. I've been able to fix this problem by rotating the map so the Pokemon is closer to the center of the screen. For whatever reason, this allows me to actually tap it and initiate the battle/capture phase. This is a faster (and more battery-efficient) workaround than shutting the whole app down and restarting it.